# Persistence Exception foreign key contraint fails in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have defined the following two classes in hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
 
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Person person;
 
}
```

When I persist a phone number object or a person object it's getting inserted properly.
But when I do

```
 Person person = session.get(Person.class,1);
        session.remove(person);
        transaction.commit();
```

I get the foreign key violation exception. But since I have declared a column as ManyToOne shouldn't hibernate automatically delete the corresponding phonnumber records? 

 I am not sure if I need to add any extra code to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bi-directional relationship, that is why you have to add the `PhoneNumber`s in your `Person` too. And use the `mappedBy` attribute to show that the `Person` is the inverse side and whenever it is deleted, please delete every phone number also.

Like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
 
}
```

Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) for more information.

Comment: Its still throwing the same error

Comment: It worked when I added the cascadeType=ALL

Comment: I intentionally left that information out of the answer for you to figure it out yourself :). Glad it worked.

Comment: What's the purpose of JoinColumn annotation, then? I don't see any use in this example. Could we use it for some purpose here?

Comment: Set the `JoinColumn` in the `Person` field of the `PhoneNumber` class to specify how will the `Person` be referenced in this table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define the relationship between Person and PhoneNumber in both classes.

The error is thrown because there are phone numbers depending on the person object you removed.
If you add `@OneToMany` you can define also the property `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` and then all phone numbers are removed consequently.

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

}
```